# Make integer in For Loop Superscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, superscript

Okay, so obviously you can't make an integer a superscript since it's a number. I need you guys. How would I take the integer from the loop and make it into a string so I can .sup() it. I'm open to using an array.

Here is the original

```js
var n;
for (let i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
  n = Math.pow(2, i);
  document.write("2 ^ " + i + " = " + n + "<br>");
}
```

Here is with an array (NOT FUNCTIONING!)

```js
var n, myArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
  myArray.push(Math.pow(2, i));
}

for (var j = 0; j <= 31; j++) {
  document.write("2" + myArray[j].sup() + " = " + n + "<br />");
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `"2 ^ <sup>" + i + "</sup> = " + n + "<br>"`?

Comment: I fixed your examples in snippets. Now there is only the last issue left, answered by @cbley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sup` is a method on `String`. So, you have to convert the number to a String first:

```
myArray[j].toString().sup()
```

Note: in many cases anything is converted to `String` implicitly, but not when you call a method on an object.

```js
var n, myArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
  myArray.push(Math.pow(2, i));
}

for (var j = 0; j <= 31; j++) {
  document.write("2" + myArray[j].toString().sup() + " = " + n + "<br />");
}
```